# how to fill combobox with ajax function?

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

I am using an ajax function for filling combobox. I have an ajax code like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    alert();

  $.ajax({

    url:'Stations.php',
    type:'POST',
  //  data: 'q=' + str, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {                
                  .append($('<option></option>', {text:value})
                  .attr('value', text));
        });
    }
  });
});
```

and my php code is like this.

```
function getStationList()
{
    $db = new DBManager();
    $mysqli = $db->db_connect();

    $query = "SELECT name FROM car";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $list = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $list[] = $row['name'];
    }

    return json_encode($list);
}
```

when i compile my php code i get an outpu like ;

["car1","car2","car3"]

i want to send this car1, car2, car3 to my box my html code is

```
<div class="content" data-role="content" id="content" >
         <div id="car">
            <select name="selectSt" class="span12" id="selectSt" > 
            <option></option>
            <option></option>
            <option></option>
            </select>                                         
         </div>
         <div id="cinfo"></div>
        <button onclick="javascript:callCarInfo.call(this,document.getElementById('selectSt').value);">Call Podcar</button>
</div>

      <div class="footer" data-role="footer"><h1>IYTE PRT&copy;</h1></div>
   </div>
```

I couldn't fill this option>/option> with car1 car2 and car3 values ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your php script (Sations.php) return data like ["car1","car2","car3"]

**Update** : text is not defined in the loop, it should be value : http://jsfiddle.net/6PEbe/1/

```
$.ajax({
    url:'Stations.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {  
           $('<option></option>', {text:value}).attr('value', value).appendTo('#selectSt');
        });
    }
  });
```

Comment: it does not work :( I couldnt see the values(from mysql which are car1,car2,car3) in box.

Comment: It looks like work but i want this values from mysql statement what should i do for this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, If I where in your shoes I would not use `append` in `each` for performance issues

Please modify the attribute_name

I would do the following

```
$.ajax({
    url:'Stations.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        var HTML = ""; 

        $.each(json, function(i, value) { 
           console.log("my val is"+value+" my key is"+i); 
           HTML = HTML+"<option>"+value+"</option>"; 
        });
        $('#selectSt').append(HTML); 
    }
  });
```

This is the best practice from performance perspective

I hope this can help :)

Comment: Do i have to change my html code ? after doing this ? because it didnt work too :(

Comment: No you don't,  can you please replace value.attribute_name with value

Comment: It is a silly question i know but what should i write instead of attribute_name ?

Comment: Remove it and open your console and type this before each console.log(json);

Comment: I am new at html and ajax functions i couldnt understood what u mean :(

Comment: Check my edit , you can open javascript or developer tools then go to console tab (using chrome or FF or IE ) you can see the returned values

Answer (score 0):

Use `children()` in the `each` callback function to append `<option>` tags:

```
$("#selectSt").children().append(valueYouWantToAdd);
```